# When to use a Cursor in Functions

Tags: sql, oracle, function, cursor

I am writing a function that takes two arguments (an ID and a Company Name) and returning a value based on these two variables as a number.  The select statements is a simple left join with two tables with `AND company_name = 'company_name_var'` and `WHERE ID = id_var`.

Could my function benefit from using a cursor?  If yes, how would I utilize it and why/what is the benefit?

SELECT STATEMENT:

```
SELECT Max(some_other_value) 
FROM   table1 
       inner join table2 
                  ON table1.id  = table2.id
                     AND company_name  = 'company_name_var' 
WHERE ID = id_var; --id and ID here represent two different columns :)
```

Comment: No. Why would you think it would?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Cursors are to process several rows. you only want to get one row. Because you only want the max value which you should insert into something like this:

```
create or replace function myfunction(i_company_name varchar2, i_id pls_integer)
return number
as
   l_maxvalue number;
begin
  SELECT Max(some_other_value) 
  into   l_maxvalue
  FROM   table1 
         inner join table2 
                    ON table1.id  = table2.id
                       AND company_name  = i_company_name
  WHERE ID = i_id;
  return l_maxvalue;
end myfunction;
```